# What offsite backup solutions allow me to control the encryption keys?

Tags: macos, security, backup, encryption

I want to find an offsite backup service where the encryption materials never leave my possession; it should be impossible for the backup provider to access the contents of my file themselves, let alone anyone that might gain access to the media used to store the files.

Does such a service/client exist, with clients for Mac OSX? I'd need decent rates, too, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) definitely supports this.  But you have to configure it before you start backing up a system.  Changing encryption types after you've already started backing up requires starting over.

Here's a link to a [support document](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/articles/encryption_key#your_private_encryption_key) with details about using a private key.  Basically, you can generate the private key it uses and never send it to the cloud.  But obviously your data is toast if you ever lose the key.